# Can I post the same content in my Wordpress site and my Blogspot?

Tags: seo, google, ranking

I have been submitting the same content in both of my sites. But the problem is that Google is not recognizing my Wordpress site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously duplicate content which is considered low quality content by Google. The Panda Algorithm is designed specifically to prevent sites like these from being in their search results. It's no surprise one isn't showing in Google's search as this is expected behavior.

Comment: thanks and what,s your advice at this context.I mean what should I do next? I wnt my word press site in the fore front

Comment: Use canonical URLs to show the Wordpress site the "main" site. I don't know if this is available on Blogspot. If not then you'll need to do 301 redirects on the Blogspot blog to the WordPress blog.

Comment: Thanks immense John.and In the morning I added a plugin 'all in one Seo plugin" for word press and selected canonical URL option.Do I have to do the same in blogspot too?.I am not a technical guy and please tell me  more about 301 redirects to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not a blogspot expert so I am unsure how to do a 301 redirect with them. I would recommend researching it and if you can't find out how asking here to see if anyone has done it and how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to do it in Blogspot, try using Google Webmaster Tools, register both sites with Google Webmaster Tools and then apply the 301 redirects.